# How can I create a wait-until-response-come-back system in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is my code:

```
import { routerRedux } from 'dva/router';
import { stringify } from 'qs';
import { UserAccountLogin, getFakeCaptcha } from '@/services/api';
import { setAuthority } from '@/utils/authority';
import { getPageQuery } from '@/utils/utils';
import { reloadAuthorized } from '@/utils/Authorized';

export default {
  namespace: 'login',

  state: {
    status: undefined,
  },

  effects: {
    *login({ payload }, { call, put }) {
      const response = yield call(UserAccountLogin, payload);
      yield put({
        type: 'changeLoginStatus',
        payload: response,
      });
    },
  },

  reducers: {
    changeLoginStatus(state, { payload }) {
      console.log(payload);                               --     undefined
      setAuthority(payload.currentAuthority);
      return {
        ...state,
        status: payload.status,
        type: payload.type,
      };
    },
  },
};
```

As I've commented in the code above, apparently that `console.log()` will be executed as the first line, So it always throws `undefined`.

As far as I know about dva, firstly `effects` will be executed and then passes the response to the `reducers`. But my code doesn't wait until the response come back. Anyway, how can I make a wait-until `const response = yield call(UserAccountLogin, payload);` get finished and them execute `yield put({` system ?

---

**Note:** Also I'm sure the data (response) will be returned as well. Because I've added a `console.log()` inside `UserAccountLogin` service and it will print the returned data after about 2 sec as well.

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed the take method this what trigger the call in your root function
takeLatest("LOGIN", login)
something like that